# Looking for uptime command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed, Permissions } = require("discord.js");
const emojis = require("../../config/emojis.json");
const db = require("quick.db");
const { player } = require("../index");
const embed = require("../structures/embeds");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  aliases: [],
  description: "test",

  /**
   *
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {Guild} guild
   */
  run: async (client, message, args, prefix, lang) => {
    try {
      message.reply({
        content: "Ping: " + client.ws.ping + "ms ",
      });
    } catch {
      console.log("rexom");
    }
  },
};
```

this is how i got my ping command, i am looking for a uptime command can someone help?
so i tested many examples it isn't working into my project, i am looking for someone provides me or gives me the code connected to the way how ping code is made because that will make the command to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`client.uptime`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=uptime) to do so. It returns how long it has been since the client last entered the `READY` state in milliseconds. See the code below to see how this works:

```js
const days = Math.floor(client.uptime / 86400000);
const hours = Math.floor(client.uptime / 3600000) % 24;
const minutes = Math.floor(client.uptime / 60000) % 60;
const seconds = Math.floor(client.uptime / 1000) % 60;
const uptime = `${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes and ${seconds} seconds`;

console.log(`The bot has been up for ${uptime}`);
```

The code above makes it into a human-readable format.

**Hoped this helped!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node's built-in `process.uptime()` function for this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "uptime",
  aliases: [],
  description: "Returns the bot's uptime in milliseconds",

  /**
   *
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {Guild} guild
   */
  run: async (client, message, args, prefix, lang) => {
    try {
      // multiply process.uptime() return value by 1000, and round it 
      // to a whole number to get ms.
      message.reply({
        content: "Uptime: " + Math.round(process.uptime() * 1000) + "ms ",
      });
    } catch {
      console.log("rexom");
    }
  },
};
```

## Edit (03/16/2021)

Since you asked in the comments for code that responds with a days/hours/minutes/seconds string as uptime instead of just the number of milliseconds like your code implied, here is how you would do that, though, in the future you should be more clear with your question:

```js
function uptimeString(seconds) {
    let days = Math.floor(seconds / (3600*24));
    seconds -= days*3600*24;
    let hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    seconds -= hours*3600;
    let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds -= minutes*60;
    return `${days} Days, ${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Minutes, and ${seconds} seconds`;
}


module.exports = {
  name: "uptime",
  aliases: [],
  description: "Returns the bot's uptime in milliseconds",

  /**
   *
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {Guild} guild
   */
  run: async (client, message, args, prefix, lang) => {
    try {
      // call the function defined above with process.uptime() as the 
      // parameter. Floor the parameter to round down.
      message.reply({
        content: uptimeString(Math.floor(process.uptime())),
      });
    } catch {
      console.log("rexom");
    }
  },
};
```

This is what the response looks like in Discord:

[image: Discord uptime command response]

My bot uses slash commands, but the code I provided will work with message.reply().

Comment: well it still gives me the code of ping, but i changed the module.exports to uptime

Comment: here is a image https://i2.paste.pics/ac45b9b07ed853899e633ebd58800e07.png

Comment: Great. I was not sure if you wanted to replace the ping command with responding with uptime or have a new command. I've edited my answer to include your changes.

Comment: It does not work , it does not give me anything the big numbers.. I want it to be in like days,hours,minutes,seconds the output for the uptime command I don’t want ping , this was just for the example of how to could would look like the output..

Comment: It does work. You asked for uptime, and the command responds with the uptime, and your example of what the response should look like had "ms" in it. It's easy to get the time in days, minutes, hours, seconds when you know the number of seconds. I've updated the answer to have this solution for you.